# Why does my code hang when calling a script in a multi-nested event function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, event-handling, nakama

I'm struggling to get my events system working in unity. I'm making an online turn based game with Nakama server.

Nakama server uses events to notify clients. I have a `MatchClient.cs` script which handles connecting to the server and matchmaking. This script invokes `MatchReady` (a UnityEvent) when the players have been matched by the matchmaker and the game is ready to start.

A `MatchEventBroadcastManager.cs` script handles match events sent to the client by the server. Game specific events are declared in this script (Such as OnOpponentMove etc. which other scripts subscribe to) It has a `MatchReady()` function that is called when MatchClient's `MatchReady` event is invoked.

**So far everything works correctly.**

This is part of the `MatchEventBroadcastManager.cs` script:

```
public delegate void MatchStartedEvent();
public static event MatchStartedEvent OnMatchStart;

public void MatchReady()
{        
    //Handle notifications from the server
    _client.Socket.OnNotification += (_, notification) =>
    {
        switch (notification.Code)
        {
            case 1:
                OnMatchStart?.Invoke();
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to use another UnityEvent for `OnMatchStart`, but it wouldn't fire any of the functions referenced in the inspector (I believe this may be something to do with nesting of events but am not certain).

This needs to be within an event as I can't subscribe to the `Socket.OnNotification` event until after the players are matched (and `Socket` is not null).

At this point we have:

- Nakama event notifies MatchClient that the players are matched.
- MatchClient notifies MatchEventBroadcastManager (among other scripts) that the match is now ready.
- MatchEventBroadcastManager subscribes to the OnNotification event of the server.
- When this event fires, OnMatchStart is invoked.

**So far everything appears to work correctly.**

**Until**

I have a `WaitingScreenMenu.cs` script that handles the waiting screen (obviously).

It subscribes to the `OnMatchStart` event and simply wants to transition to the next menu.

```
private void Start()
{
    MatchEventBroadcastManager.OnMatchStart += MatchStarted;

    Debug.Log("Menu manager: ");
    Debug.Log(_menuManager.name);
}

public void MatchStarted()
{
    Debug.Log("Menu manager: ");
    Debug.Log(_menuManager.name);
    Debug.Log("Test after");
}
```

I removed the transition to the next menu and just try and access an outside object to test, **but this is the point execution hangs.**

In the debug output when the game starts `_menuManager.name` prints correctly to the console.

When MatchStarted is called `"Menu manager: "` is printed, **but nothing else.**

If I comment out `Debug.Log(_menuManager.name);` then it prints:

```
"Menu manager: "
"Test after"
```

I have tried with other scripts, with the same results. I have called the function from within one that is subscribed to an event that isn't nested and it functions correctly.

I'm attempting to separate the game logic into manageable pieces, but it seems the only way to handle the events is to have everything handled by `MatchClient.cs` and have a gigantic, unwieldy mess.

**Is Unity really limited in this way with regards to events or am I missing something?**

Thanks for your help in advance.

Dan

Comment: Set a break point in Visual Studio and use the debugger.

Comment: When I do this, I break on the invokation then F11 through the lines until I get to the problem line, then visual studio just waits on the _menu Manager.name line.

Comment: Stepping through/into isn't the only way to use the debugger. You can examine variable values as well. What is the value of the manager just before that debug line?

Comment: Thanks for your help Draco18s. That has helped me solve the problem. Examining the menuManager value with the event actually showed a UnityException. The event was being called from an async method it seems and I cannot communicate with the UnityEngine from a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Visual Studio debugger uncovered the error. Breaking at the event and examining the value of `_menuManager` showed a UnityException. `UnityException: get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread.`

The event was being invoked from an async method. Looking into it, I've found that you can't communicate with the UnityEngine from a separate thread.

Instead of invoking my event directly in the `Socket.OnNotification` event, I instead set a flag that is checked in `Update()`, which subsequently invokes my event on the main thread.

The replaced parts of the `MatchEventBroadcastManager.cs` script:

```
private bool notifMatchStarted;
public UnityEvent MatchStarted;

void Update()
{
    //Invoke events here to guarantee they are called from the main thread.
    if(notifMatchStarted)
    {
        MatchStarted.Invoke();
        notifMatchStarted = false;
    }
}

public void MatchReady()
{
    //Handle notifications from the server
    _client.Socket.OnNotification += (_, notification) =>
    {
        switch (notification.Code)
        {
            case 1:
                notifMatchStarted = true;
                break;
        }
    };
}
```